# A better way of parsing an int from a string

Tags: c#, string, string-parsing

I'm trying to see if there is a different/better way of parsing a string that I have.

The string is "#def xyz[timer=50, fill=10]".
From this string I am trying to retrieve the timer and fill values.

The code I currently have is:

```
string def = "#def xyz[timer=50, fill=10]";
string _timer = def.Remove(def.IndexOf(","));
_timer = _timer.Remove(0, _timer.IndexOf("=", _timer.IndexOf("timer")) + 1);

string _fill = def.Remove(def.IndexOf("]"));
_fill = _fill.Remove(0, _fill.IndexOf("=", _fill.IndexOf("fill")) + 1);

int timer = Int32.Parse(_timer);
int fill = Int32.Parse(_fill);
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried regular expression?

Comment: What do you mean by *better*? Easier to read? More performant?

Comment: k0stya, platon No, I haven't tried regular expressions yet. System Down Yeah something with better performance. The def string can get a bit longer than what I have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would probably use a regular expression. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // You can create the regex once and reuse it, of course. Adjust
        // as necessary if the name isn't always "xyz" for example.
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^#def xyz\[timer=(\d+), fill=(\d+)\]$");
        string input = "#def xyz[timer=50, fill=10]";
        Match match = regex.Match(input);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            int fill = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
            int timer = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("Fill={0}, timer={1}", fill, timer);
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- This only deals with non-negative integers
- It will fail (with an exception) if the value is out of range for an `int`

I'd say it indicates what you're doing more clearly than those `Remove` calls though...

Answer (score 1):

```
      Match m = Regex.Match("#def xyz[timer=50, fill=10]", "timer=([0-9]+?), fill=([0-9]+?)[]]");

      string timer = m.Result("$1");
      string fill = m.Result("$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using split when I can, it is much faster than regex in most cases -- I didn't test but I expect it would be faster here.  Of course there is very little error checking in this code.

```
void Main()
{
  string def = "#def xyz[timer=50, fill=10]";

  string [] inBracket = def.Split("[]".ToCharArray());

  string [] elements = inBracket[1].Split(",".ToCharArray());

  int timer = int.Parse(elements[0].Split("=".ToCharArray())[1]);

  int fill = int.Parse(elements[1].Split("=".ToCharArray())[1]);

  Console.WriteLine("timer = "+timer.ToString());
  Console.WriteLine("fill = "+fill.ToString());

}
```